# Another suitable word for attached

Tags: word-request

I am looking for a replacement to the word *attached* in:

> “I am ***attached*** to my current lifestyle and resist changing it”.

What’s another suitable word I can use?

Comment: This question could be improved if you told us why you are looking for another word besides *attached*. (The word _attached_ seems to work just fine in this case.) You also might want to read our [_"Not so fast"_ meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the word [accustomed](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/accustomed), which means "usual".

> I am **accustomed** to my current lifestyle and resist changing it.

Alternatively, you can also use "used to", which is close in meaning to "familiar with".

> I am **used to** my current lifestyle and resist changing it

Answer (score 2):

A word that has, to me, a similar 'feel' as 'attached' is *partial*.

> I am partial to my current lifestyle and resist changing it.